# Java Concurrency - Implementing Monitors using Semaphores - All threads getting stuck in waiting state, something wrong with my understanding

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, monitor

I'm trying to implement monitors using semaphores in Java, to created a bounded buffer with some writer threads and some reader threads.

So far, I do the following:

For each class that we may want to lock on (i.e. before, we would have had a synchronized code block in it) I add two semaphores, one binary one to lock at the start of a block and unlock at the end (ensuring that only one critical section of code can be executed at any one time) and another to act as the unit that passes down notify and notifyAll signals.  I also create an integer counter to keep track of threads that have called wait.

Then at the start of a synchronized block of code, I get the lock for the 'monitor' and then call my replacement for the wait instruction if necessary.

I have two threads constantly calling put and two threads constantly calling get.  And after anywhere between 1 second and 10 seconds, all threads get stuck.

Somehow they all got stuck waiting, and I really can't see how!  I've spent a few days thinking this one over.  Any ideas?

Does anyone have any ideas what's causing all these threads to get stuck at this point?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but, it made me think of this: [Dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)

Comment: `blocksWaitingCount` should be volatile or an `AtomicInteger` in my opinion: else there is no guarantee that other threads will see an updated value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `notifyAll()` implementation is flawed. To do this correctly, you need an interlocked compare-and-exchange operation (like what `AtomicInteger` et al provide). The issue is that in your loop:

```
    // Equivalent of notifyAll()
    for (int i = val(); i>0; i--) {
        dec();
        notifyCalled.release();
    }
```

Two threads can be racing and both observe `val()` as 1, and then both `dec()` calls will succeed and `blocksWaitingCount` will be -1. Then, because `blocksWaitingCount` no longer matches the count of threads waiting on a `notifyCalled` permit, future invocations of `notifyAll()` will fail to notify all blocking threads (since even when `i == 0`, there is still a thread blocking). Repeat for a few iterations and `notifyAll()` will eventually stop releasing any threads at all, and all threads will be blocked.

Comment: Hmm, good point. But in your `wait()` implementation, `inc()` is not guarded by `monitorSemaphore`, so you still risk the `blocksWaitingCount` changing between the calls to `val()` and `dec()`, right?

Comment: The reason for `blocksWaitingCount` is because you are trying to ensure that every `notifyCalled.acquire()` is paired with exactly one `notifyCalled.release()`, right? But because the `wait()` implementation doesn't hold the `monitorSemaphore` while doing its `inc(); notifyCalled.acquire()` you risk the `notifyAll()` implementation doing its `release()` before the corresponding `acquire()` ever happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot control which thread will succeed in notifyCalled.acquire().

For example consider this situation:

1. Thread A waiting in get
2. Thread B executes put twice and fills the buffer. There is only one thread waiting so it makes 1 call to notifyCalled.release()
3. Thread C executes put and since the buffer is full it enters the wait block.
4. The notifyCalled.release() in 3 causes notifyCalled.aquire() to succeed in Thread C rather than Thread A

Since the buffer is still full Thread C (and all other put operations) enters an reenters the while loop and waits again and Thread B will never receive the release it is waiting for.

**SOLUTION**

The problem arises when a permit obtained in the `wait` block of put operation is not used because the buffer is full (or the opposite for a get operation). To avoid this a flag can used to release the permit so that another waiting thread with the opposite operation can try to obtain it.

Additionally, as noted by Daniel Pryden `inc()` should also be moved inside the monitorSemaphore lock to avoid race conditions.

Note that this makes the synchronized blocks for modifying `blocksWaitingCount` unnecessary (although since they are uncontended they have a minimal effect on performance).

Here is the revised code

```
public class BufferNonSync {

    private int[] buffer = new int[] { 0};
    private int start = 0;
    private int last = 0;
    private final int size = 1;
    private int numberInBuffer = 0;

    // Monitor variables
    private Semaphore monitorSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    private Semaphore notifyCalled = new Semaphore(0);

    private int blocksWaitingCount = 0;

    public void put(int input, int id) throws InterruptedException {
        monitorSemaphore.acquire();

        boolean acquired = false;
        while (numberInBuffer == size) {
            // Equivalent of wait()
            if (acquired) {
                dec();
                notifyCalled.release();
            }
            inc();
            monitorSemaphore.release();
            notifyCalled.acquire();
            monitorSemaphore.acquire();
            acquired = true;
        }

        // Critical section
        buffer[last] = input;
        last = (last + 1) % size;
        numberInBuffer++;

        // Equivalent of notifyAll()
        for (int i = val(); i > 0; i--) {
            dec();
            notifyCalled.release();
        }

        monitorSemaphore.release();
    }

    public int get(int id) throws InterruptedException {
        monitorSemaphore.acquire();

        boolean acquired = false;
        while (numberInBuffer == 0) {
            // Equivalent of wait()
            if (acquired) {
                dec();
                notifyCalled.release();
            }
            inc();
            monitorSemaphore.release();
            notifyCalled.acquire();
            monitorSemaphore.acquire();
            acquired = true;
        }

        // Critical section
        int temp = buffer[start];
        start = (start + 1) % size;
        numberInBuffer--;

        // Equivalent of notifyAll()
        for (int i = val(); i > 0; i--) {
            dec();
            notifyCalled.release();
        }

        monitorSemaphore.release(); 

        return temp;
    }

    private void inc() {
        blocksWaitingCount++;
    }

    private void dec() {
        blocksWaitingCount--;
    }

    private int val() {
        return blocksWaitingCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: put threads only need to be notified by get threads and vice versa. Maybe you could divide your notifyCalled in two separate objects